# way to store POST variables when using django

Tags: django-templates, django-views

with a form am searching schools nearby and displaying them as table.

inside views.py

> ```
> def method1:
>    printquery = request.POST.copy()
>    zip = printquery['zip']
>    if not zip:
>        city = printquery['city']
>        state = printquery['state']
>        zip = getZip(city,state)      
>    results = zipObj.getSchools(zip);
>    render_to_response('some.html',{'results':results,'query':printquery,})
> ```

inside template

```
<form id="print-search" target="_blank" action="" method="post" name="print">
     <input type="hidden" value="{%if query%}{{query}}{%endif%} name="query"/>
     <input type ="submit" value="Print the Results" name="submitPrint"/>
</form>
<table>
 {% block xxx%}displays schools result {%endblock%}
</table>
```

when the "Print the results" button is clicked.I want to use 'query',
do the search again and print in separate page[I have no choice of storing in session id].
Problem am facing is, `{{query}}` is a turing to a string i.e.,`u"{'zip': u'76123'"}` on which i cannot do something like `query['zip']`,
Is there a way to solve this. Ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of taking the whole dictionary as value, do something like this

```
<form id="print-search" target="_blank" action="" method="post" name="providerprint">
  <input type="hidden" value="{%if query.zip %}{{query.zip}}{%else%}""{%endif%}" name="zip"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="{%if query.city %}{{query.ciyt}}{%else%}""{%endif%}" name="city"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="{%if query.state %}{{query.state}}{%else%}""{%endif%}" name="state"/>
  <input type ="submit" value="Print this Search" name="submitProviderprint"/>
</form>
```

inside the views.py we can access this as

```
zip = params['zip']
city = params['city']
state = params['state']
```

and it worked for me.:)